# How to solve definite integral

Tags: definite-integrals, exponential-function

Is there an easy way to compute the definite integral
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} x^{n}e^{\mathrm{i}a x^2-\mathrm{i}b x}\,dx,
\end{align*}
where $ n\in \mathbb{N} $ and $ a,b\in \mathbb{R} ?$ I found some formulas for $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$ or $\int_{0}^{\infty}$ but I want to solve for finite limits.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's doable, but perhaps it makes your life a bit simpler to realize that
\begin{align*}
I&=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{\mathrm{i}a x^2-\mathrm{i}b x}\,dx
\end{align*}

So that $$\frac{\partial^nI}{\partial b^n}=(-i)^n\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}x^ne^{\mathrm{i}a x^2-\mathrm{i}b x}\,dx.$$

This identity should at least make it easier to get $I$ in terms of special functions.